# The value 'hibernate.current_session_context_class' is invalid according to its datatype 'String'

Tags: c#, nhibernate, session-management, sessioncontext

I have an app that uses Nhibernate. This is my first app using it so I am newbie. I am trying to test my first get method.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  IList<Person> persons =
    SessionManager
      .SessionFactory
      .GetCurrentSession()
      .CreateCriteria(typeof(Person))
      .List<Person>();
}
```

Here's the session mgr code:

```
public static partial class SessionManager 
{
  private static readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

  static SessionManager()
  {
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration().Configure();
    _sessionFactory = 
      Fluently
        .Configure(cfg)
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(typeof(SessionManager).Assembly))
        .BuildSessionFactory();
        //CurrentSessionContext.Bind(_sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession());
  }

  public static ISession OpenSession()
  {
    return _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
  }

  public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
  {
    get { return _sessionFactory; }
  }
}
```

But everytime I run the app and click the btn. it throws an exception with inner exception msg:

> "The 'name' attribute is invalid - The value
>   'hibernate.current_session_context_class' is invalid according to its
>   datatype 'String' - The Enumeration constraint failed."}

Here's my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">managed</property>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=localhost\MSSQLSERVERR2;Database=PersonSearch;Trusted_Connection=True</property>
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
      <property name="cache.use_minimal_puts">false</property>
      <property name="use_outer_join">false</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

Originally, I did not put

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">managed</property>
```

but it is giving me an error:

> No CurrentSessionContext configured (set the property
>   current_session_context_class)!

Answer (score 0):

If in a web application, try the following:

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">managed_web</property>
```

If in a winform application, try the following:

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread_static</property>
```